# Windows batch, show total bytes current folder and sub folders

Tags: windows, batch-file

With Windows XP and Windows 7 batch file ...

With a one (1) line batch output, How to show total bytes in
current folder and all sub folders?

`dir /s` does output the desired number of bytes near the bottom of the output.

How to output that information? Like

```
1234567890 bytes
```

Here are 6 examples of what is working in a batch.
We have 2 methods showing 3 results each:

```
"d:\temp2" folders (-system -hidden) = 5921  
"d:\temp2" folders (+system +hidden) = 5926  
"d:\temp2" files ................... = 42792  


"d:\temp2" folders (-system -hidden) = 5921  
"d:\temp2" folders (+system +hidden) = 5926  
"d:\temp2" files ................... = 42792
```

The above question is asking how to output with batch

```
"d:\temp2" bytes .................., = 1234567890
```

The 6 working batch file commands are:

First 3 are one line commands

```
echo One line command outputs
```

1

```
echo echo | set /p dummyName=""d:\temp2" folders (-system -hidden) = " && (dir /s /b /ad-s-h "d:\temp2" |find /c /v "")
```

2

```
echo echo | set /p dummyName=""d:\temp2" folders (+system +hidden) = " && (dir /s /b /ad     "d:\temp2" |find /c /v "")
```

3

```
echo echo | set /p dummyName=""d:\temp2" files                     = " && (dir /s /b /ad-d   "d:\temp2" |find /c /v "")
```

4

```
set count=   
for /f %%a in ('dir /s /b /ad-s-h "d:\temp2" ^|find /c /v "" ') do set count=%%a  
echo "d:\temp2" folders (-system -hidden) = %count%
```

5

```
set count=   
for /f %%a in ('dir /s /b /ad     "d:\temp2" ^|find /c /v "" ') do set count=%%a  
echo "d:\temp2" folders (+system +hidden) = %count%
```

6

```
set count=   
for /f %%a in ('dir /s /b /a-d    "d:\temp2" ^|find /c /v "" ') do set count=%%a  
echo "d:\temp2" files                     = %count%
```

---

With a one (1) line batch output, How to show total bytes in
current folder and all sub folders?

--

Comment: Edit your question and indent code with 4 spaces, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set DNAME=D:\temp2

for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4" %%a in (`dir %DNAME% /s/w/-c ^| findstr "File(s)"`) do set BYTES=%%c
echo %BYTES% bytes
```

This outputs total number of bytes for `d:\temp2` and its subdirectories.